# Server permissions issue with latest WordPress upgrade

Tags: nginx, wordpress, ubuntu-14.04, file-permissions

I'm running WordPress version 4.7.1 on a few machines (Ubuntu 14.04.5 + Nginx) and want to upgrade to 4.7.3. However when I try to run the updated through WP-Admin it gives:

> The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.: wp-admin/includes/update-core.php

So I thought was some permissions issue, I updated using the following:

```
find /var/www/site -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find /var/www/site -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
chmod 600 /var/www/site/wp-config.php
```

But that too did not correct the issue - still gives same error.

If I run `chown -R www-data:www-data .` it seems to work fine but worried about security...any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> Typically, all files should be owned by your user (ftp) account on
>   your web server, and should be writable by that account. On shared
>   hosts, files should never be owned by the webserver process itself
>   (sometimes this is www, or apache, or nobody user).

Reference - [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Here's a script I run on my webroot to set permissions. This is on my AWS EC instance. I have a little more on permissions [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-3-migrating-wordpress-sites-into-aws/#wfp).

```
chown -R myusername:www-data /var/www/*
# This part runs for each wordpress install individually
find /var/www/sp -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www/wp -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find /var/www/wp/wp-content/uploads -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find /var/www/wp/wp-content/plugins -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find /var/www/wp/wp-content/themes -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
chmod 440 /var/www/wp/wp-config.php
chmod -R g+s /var/www/wp/
```

My web server user, nginx, is a member of the www-data group

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Sorry I didn't note that in the original post - this is not shared hosting. These  are EC2 instances on AWS. But we did not enable FTP on the server for security purposes...is it required that we enable FTP? Or is it fine that we use the www-data:www-data?

Comment: Answer above expanded. Doesn't matter where you're hosted, same guidelines apply. I run Wordpress on EC2. sftp is part of the included ssh daemon.

Comment: Thanks for the script. Im assuming the first line is meant to be run from the document root location of WP. However, now when I try to upgrade (either plugin or WP) it says "Could not create directory." Here is screenshot of plugins directory so you can see the permissions. https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbmv5vdlhw6xi5g/wp-plugins-folder.png?dl=0

Comment: This of course is a permissions problem. I can't fully answer it is I don't have all the information. Work out what folder is trying to be made, by which user, then work out what permissions are required. For example I have php running as the user who owns those files, which is probably not the way it's meant to be done, but I did it a long time ago and haven't needed to change. Read the Wordpress Codex page I linked to fully, I haven't done that recently but it probably has the answer. Other pages say make www-data the owner of the webroot, I'm not really an expert, read around.

Comment: So I was able to determine the user for the nginx daemon which is in fact www-data. Makes sense that when I chown the document root for this user that it works perfect. My only concern was the security part... :)

Comment: Nginx runs as root but it starts its worker processes as whatever you specify in nginx.conf. If the files are writable by the web server then you're more open to compromise when someone finds a security hole in Wordpress, either Nginx or PHP can write those files. My server is probably vulnerable to the same problem, php runs as file owners, but it hasn't happened in the past year. Ideally you want the files owned by a different user, but give Nginx/PHP group read permissions. Some folders they need write permissions, wp-content at least.